# Adding arrow image to jQuery accordian

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I was fiddling with [jQuery accordian](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

I copy pasted the minimal code of default accordian and pasted it in local html file, downloaded jquery-1.8.3.js, jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css locally. I also included collapsed.png and expanded.png images(in images folder) and put all them in proper folders and linked them properly. Everything was working nicely only that arrow images were not appearing at all.

**accordianDemo.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui.css" />  
  <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
        //-------------------notice---------------------------------------//
    var icons = {
              header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
              activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
            };
        //----------------------------------------------------------------//
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        icons: icons  //<<<<---------------------------notice---------//
    });
  });
  </script>
      //-------------------notice---------------------------------------//
  <style type="text/css">
    .ui-icon-circle-arrow-e
    {
        background-image: url("images/collapsed.png");
    }
    .ui-icon-circle-arrow-s
    {
        background-image: url("images/expanded.png");
    }
  </style>
      //----------------------------------------------------------------//    
</head>
<style>
    #accordion
    {
        width:650px;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>    
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

The output was like this:

[image]

**[Edit:added folder hierarchy snapshot]** My folder hierarchy loos looks this and my code is in tempaccr.html:

[image]

As you can see I have all links and styles properly set up and also defined CSS classes to toggle the arrows when the section is collapsed and expanded, why arrows are not appearing? Any reason.

Comment: Are you hosting images too for that icon?

Comment: try using cdn hosted ui css: `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`

Comment: may be path is not correct for the images.

Comment: One better way to solve this is using chrome console, inspect the position where image should be and search at css rules for the images path.

Comment: @Jai hey using hosted CSS worked, but why am puzzled please explain why? It seems that in CSS they used relative paths for their background images, and we browse those relative paths evaluates to the images on their server. Is it like that? Because when I save same CSS locally and fire the page it doesnt work. But then how we can do it to add our own images. Just see how I tried by looking to new snapshot I just added about my folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-e
{
    background-image: url("../images/collapsed.png");
}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-s
{
    background-image: url("../images/expanded.png");
}
</style>
```